# Eclipse SWT: How to scroll Text programmatically

Tags: java, scroll, eclipse-rcp

I have a Text control on a shell

```
Text text = new Text(contentComp, SWT.NONE | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

Its text value would be set by a background thread. For example, the thread may append 1000 lines to the Text. I want to make the Text automatically scroll on the vertical scroll bar while its contents get updated. I tried to set selection in its Modify event listener but it does not work. Any idea how to do that? I cannot use StyledText so there is no setTopIndex method available. Thanks.

Comment: `Text` also has a `setTopIndex()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I use SWT library provided by Eclipse RAP platform. It's very similar to the standard SWT library but occasionally there is difference. The Text on RAP platform does not have the setTopIndex() method.

Comment: If you are using RAP, you should tag the post with `eclipse-rap`. If `setSelection()` does not work it is most likely a bug in RAP and you could file a [bug report](https://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/). Make sure that you tried with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround that can scroll a (RAP) Text widget by code. However it has limitation. I am not sure whether there is a good solution for this problem. Here is the workaround: Use a ScrolledComposite as the parent of the Text widget.

```
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.NONE|SWT.V_SCROLL);
Text text = new Text(sc, SWT.NONE|SWT.MULTI);
```

The point is to update the ScrollableComposite#setMinHeight(int) when new data is appended. If this is done in modify listener, then both sc and text would display a scroll bar when text size grows larger than its default on the parent. It looks a little strange but as long as the setMinHeight(int) is updated correctly, calling

```
sc.setOrigin(sc.getOrigin().x, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

will scroll the text down to the bottom.

Another issue with this workaround is that if you need to dispose controls and re-create them later on with the previously appended data, the auto-scroll won't work any more as text will be resized to fit the sc, thus sc minHeight does not work to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the solution using `ScrolledComposite` to work. The output was being written to the `Text` field, but I couldn't see it. It's like the `ScrolledComposite` was hiding the text.

Instead, I got it to work like this:

```
Text outputText = new Text(parent, SWT.NONE | SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
outputText.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
    @Override
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event) {
        Text text = (Text) event.widget;
        // position the cursor after the last character
        text.setSelection(text.getCharCount());
    }
});
```